# Modal prompt class name in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

So I'm completely drawing a blank on the name of the class that draws one of these modal prompts with multiple options.  I've attached a screenshot.  It's the prompt that's confirming whether or not the user wants to sign out.

[image: modal prompt screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a `UIActionSheet`, Read [UIActionSheet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

### Example

In your header, you need to add the `<UIActionSheetDelegate>` protocol. Then in your `@implementation` this is how you would call this specific sheet:

```
UIActionSheet * sampleSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you'd like to sign out from Path?" delegate:self 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Sign Out" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[sampleSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
[sampleSheet showInView:self.view];
```

And this is how you would handle the sheet:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    switch ( buttonIndex )
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"User Chose Cancel");
            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"User Chose to Sign out.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wish there was an easy way to pull this up ... did you just remember off the top of your head?

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example. you should still read the class reference to learn more on how this works and to familiarize yourself with this class.

Answer (score 0):

You want [UIActionSheet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

See UIActionSheet, I think that's the class you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) { 

    //give the user an option to choose an image from their library or take a new photo...
    popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose From Library", nil];

    popupQuery.tag = 0;
}
else {

    //give the user an option to choose an image from their library or take a new photo...
    popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Choose From Library", nil];

    popupQuery.tag = 1;
}
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery showInView:[self.view window]];

[popupQuery release];
```